# Make Parent Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

can someone help me with jquery. i have a html TAG like this

`<p class="celak">hohohohoho</p>`

and i want to make the output (give its parent) be like this

`<div class="celak-parent"><p class="celak">hohohohoho</p></div>`

is there somebody know which jquery method can do that?

`$('.class').???`

sorry if my write not very good.
this first time i asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wrap method is what you need. (http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$('.celak').wrap('<div class="cleak-parent"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your div does not exist at all you might use the `wrap` method:

```
$("p.celak").wrap("<div class='celak-parent'/>");
```

If your div does exist you can easily target and modify it with the `parent` method:

```
$("p.celak").parent().addClass('celak-parent');
```